# Getting only certain data from list in document in Mongo

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
[
  {
    "_id": "",
    "at": IsoDate(2022-11-19 10:00:00),
    "areaId": 3,
    "data": [
      {
        "label": 1,
        "name": "a",
        "sec": 34,
        "x": 10.3,
        "y": 23.3
      },
      {
        "label": 1,
        "name": "a",
        "sec": 36,
        "x": 10.3,
        "y": 23.3
      },
      {
        "label": 1,
        "name": "c",
        "sec": 37,
        "x": 10.3,
        "y": 23.3
      }
      ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "",
    "at": IsoDate(2022-11-19 10:01:00),
    "areaId": 3,
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "a",
        "label": 1,
        "sec": 10,
        "x": 10.3,
        "y": 23.3
      },
      {
        "label": 2,
        "name": "b",
        "sec": 12,
        "x": 10.3,
        "y": 23.3
      }
      ]
  }
  ]
```

I have a mongo bson data as above. This data holds areaId based login information in 1-minute packets. Getting all label=1 data in the date range given here. I want to get it in the most performance way since the data size is very large.
This query can be in the same data format and in the data list, only the ones with a label of 1 can be returned. Do you think it's a good idea?

How can I write a query for this? Could it be a bsondocument query too, since I'm extracting the query in c#?

Comment: Maybe refactoring your schema to store the array entries in their own collection? You can index the resulting collection for performance boost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $match: {
         at: {
            $gt: ISODate('2022-11-01'), $lt: ISODate('2022-12-01')
         }
      }
   },
   { $set: { data: { $filter: { input: "$data", cond: { $eq: ["$$this.label", 1] } } } } }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/k8asHuRXVV0)

Comment: What to do if the label value comes as an array here? And how can I specify the date range?

Comment: In order to check for a single value in an array, you can use `{ $in: [1, "$$this.label"] }`. In order to check for multiple values, you can either use `{$or: []}` or you check the size of intersection: `{ $gt: [{$size: { $setIntersection: [ "$$this.label", [1,2,3] ] } }, 0] }`

Comment: For date ranges, see my updated answer.

Comment: Any chance we can do this with Mongodb.driver library? It was a confusing query for me. How can I export this query in c#?

Comment: I never used the C# driver, sorry. The methods should be the same, just the syntax would be different.